# MaterialTable - A state mutation was detected between dispatches

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, material-ui, material-table

I have two sets of data that i want to display in table data so depending on the requirement, trying to set state of tabledata with different data.

Table Component:

```
<Grid item xs={12} md={8}>
  {this.state.showTable && this.state.tableData !== null && (
       <MaterialTable
         title="Manage Blogs"
         columns={this.state.columns}
         data={this.state.tableData}
         actions={[
         {
           icon: "open_in_new",
           tooltip: "Open Blog",
           onClick: (blog, rowData) => {
            // Do save operation
            this.props.history.push("partner/blog/" + rowData._id);
             }
            }
          ]}
        />
  )}
</Grid>
```

Following are the two places, where i am changing state of tableData:

```
  changeSelectedComponent = label => {
    debugger;
    if (this.state.selectedComponent.toString() !== label)
      this.setState(state => ({ selectedComponent: label }));
    if (label === "Blogs") {
      if (
        this.props.partnerBlogs === null &&
        this.props.apiCallsInProgress === 0
      ) {
        this.props.actions
          .loadPartnerBlogs(this.props.auth0UserProfile.sub)
          .catch(error => {
            alert("Loading events failed" + error);
          });
      } else if (this.props.apiCallsInProgress === 0) {
        this.setState({ tableData: this.props.partnerBlogs, showTable: true });
      }
    } else if (label === "Your Events") {
      if (
        this.props.partnerEvents === null &&
        this.props.apiCallsInProgress === 0
      ) {
        this.props.actions
          .loadPartnerEvents(this.props.auth0UserProfile.sub)
          .catch(error => {
            alert("Loading events failed" + error);
          });
      } else if (this.props.apiCallsInProgress === 0) {
        this.setState({ tableData: this.props.partnerEvents, showTable: true });
      }
    }
  };
```

Another place after receiving new props:

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    debugger;
    if (
      this.props.partnerBlogs !== nextProps.partnerBlogs &&
      nextProps.apiCallsInProgress === 0
    ) {
      this.setState({
        tableData: nextProps.partnerBlogs,
        showTable: true
      });
    }
    if (
      this.props.partnerEvents !== nextProps.partnerEvents &&
      nextProps.apiCallsInProgress === 0
    ) {
      this.setState({
        tableData: nextProps.partnerEvents,
        showTable: true
      });
    }
  }
```

Initial state of tableData is null. There is no issue when i am setting state for the first time but while changing state, getting following error

> A state mutation was detected between dispatches, in the path
>   `partnerEvents.0.tableData`. This may cause incorrect behavior.
>   (http://redux.js.org/docs/Troubleshooting.html#never-mutate-reducer-arguments)

Don't know what's wrong in my code, Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you share your redux code?  Warning seems to imply the error is in a reducer.  Can you provide a [minimal, complete, and verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces the issue?

Comment: That particular error sounds like it's actually happening _outside_ the reducers.  My first guess is that the `<MaterialTable>` is perhaps somehow mutating its data?

Comment: Yes i tried so many approaches and also with one state for the table but it doesn't seems to be working whenever i am trying to change the table data through state

Comment: @markerikson do you have any suggestion that i can try thanks

Comment: Worth noting that this is an open issue with Material Table. There is a feature request to have a no-mutate option. See: [link](https://github.com/mbrn/material-table/issues/1371)

Answer (score 3):

materialTable mutated your data adding the object TableData that contain row 'Id' and 'checked' elements, so I recommend use this in your code if you want to avoid the mutation:

`data={this.state.yourData.map(x =>Object.assign({}, x))}`

Please, let me know if that avoid the mutation issues that you are having.

Best Regards

Comment: This does prevent the mutation issue from occurring, but it has side-effects. I'm enabling row selection, and when I use code like this it results in the checked rows not tracking properly. If I select a single row, it's fine. If I select a second row, the first-select row is then unchecked. Effectively I can only select one row.

Comment: You should keep a reference of checked rows outside of the table, and update this field before send the data to the table. For example check this code: 
////////////////////////////////////
response.data.forEach((row, i) => {
        const idsSelected = this.state.myListChecked.map(u => u.Id);
        if (idsSelected.includes(row.Id)) {
          row.tableData = {
            checked: true
          };
        }
      });
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: Thanks @Orestes. So I'm making new data array using setState and give this data array to the table. Then in useEffect I copy the data I want to use to generate table using the Object.assign method. Then iterate through that array to set the tableData.checked value based on another array of selectedIds and assign that array to setState. By table selection works and I do NOT get the mutation error.